# Load a data uri string in react-player

Tags: react-native, react-player

I would like to load a *data uri string*

`data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRuR+JwNXQVZFZm10IBAAAAAB`

string into a [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) component or *any other video player in react*.

I only find the possibility to load *url* from local videos or e.g. youtube.

Hence, my question is, wether this is possible.